# automatic button icon support for themes Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, button, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, themes

WP supports a dark and a light theme. The user can change the theme on the phone to either light or dark, and the specific attributes will change accordingly as well, such as text colour and so on.

I am trying to create buttons that have icon images in them, to automatically change to support the theme that the user chooses.

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Here is the way I am doing my current buttons:

```
    <Button Name="button" Margin="250,443,86,44" VerticalAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource roundButton}" Height="120" Click="button_click" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="120">
            <Image Source="/Assets/Tiles/picture.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    </Button>
```

Comment: Is this for the appbar, or within the page proper?

Comment: Sorry, within the page.

Comment: Can you show your hard way ?

Comment: if the answer is satisfactory please mark it as correct so it can help others as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. You can detect which theme is set when the app runs and change your UI elements accordingly. Im doing this in the OnNavigatedTo method in the MainPage.xaml page to change the elements in the MainPage.xaml

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    var theme = (Visibility)Resources["PhoneLightThemeVisibility"];

    if (theme == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
    {
        // Change the UI for Light theme
    }
    else
    {
        // Change the UI for Dark theme
    }
}
```

try this. This should work for you.